# Prevent file from generating new build - Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I have an application with nuxt.js / Vue.

I created a Webpack Plugin so that with each file changed, generate an `index.js` in a certain directory.

The problem is that when `index.js` is generated, Webpack recognizes this as a new change and build again, so it stays in that infinite loop ...

To detect changes, I'm using [webpack hooks](https://webpack.js.org/api/compiler-hooks/#beforecompile)

```
compiler.hooks.beforeCompile.tapAsync('MyPlugin', (params, callback) => {
  // script to generate an index.js in a given directory
});
```

how can I prevent `index.js` from triggering a new build?

> Updating the question for better understanding

I'm working on an application made with vue.js | nuxt.js and this component structure

```
├── components
│   ├── quarks
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── bosons
│   │   └── GridLayout.vue
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── atoms
│   │   └── ButtonStyle.vue
│   │   └── InputStyle.vue
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── molecules
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── organisms
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── ...
└─────
```

I need to do named and grouped imports, like this:

```
import { ButtonStyle, InputStyle } from '@/components/atoms/'
```

but for this to work out I would need to have an index.js inside each folder exporting component by component, example

```
├── components
│   ├── atoms
│   │   └── ButtonStyle.vue
│   │   └── InputStyle.vue
│   │   └── index.js
└─────
```

and in `index.js`

```
export { default as ButtonStyled } from './ButtonStyled.vue'
export { default as InputStyle } from './InputStyle.vue'
```

But doing this work manually can be a very tiresome task. Every time you create, delete, rename a component, you would have to update the `index.js` of your respective folder.

so I started to develop a solution

in `nuxt.config.js`

```
import NamedExports from './plugins/NamedExports.js'

export default {
  // ... other config here ...
  build: {
    plugins: [
      new NamedExports()
    ],
  }
}
```

in `plugins/NamedExports.js`

```
const pluginName = 'NamedExports'
const { exec } = require('child_process')

class NamedExports {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.beforeCompile.tap(pluginName, (params, callback) => {
      exec('sh plugins/shell.sh', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        console.log(stdout)
        console.log(stderr)
      })
    })
  }
}

export default NamedExports
```

`plugins/shell.sh`

```
parameters=$(ls components)
for item in ${parameters[*]}
do
    ls components/$item/ | grep -v index.js | sed 's#^\([^.]*\).*$#export { default as \1 } from "./&"#' > components/$item/index.js
done
```

but whenever the plugin creates an `index.js`, a new build is triggered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a hook that runs only once and I use `chokidar` to listen for changes in the components directory

```
compiler.hooks.entryOption.tap('MyPlugin', (context, entry) => {
  // generates index.js
  // Watch a directory with chokidar 
});
```

I turned this into a library, maybe it helps other people

### [Weback Plugin - named-exports](https://github.com/yungsilva19/named-exports)

Answer (score 2):

Have you added the new file/directory to WebPacks exclude list? If not, the watchOptions.ignore property might be just what your looking for:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/

Hope this helps

Comment: I already tried this option, and I can make the webpack stop observing the `index.js`, but this causes another problem.

When my script `updates` the contents of `index.js`, the webpack will not recognize these changes and will be as if it had not updated.

Comment: Hmm... Perhaps I misunderstood the question then. So that we can understand correctly and attempt to better answer let me ask. Are you saying you want WebPack to detect content changes to the file, but ignore the file if the file is replaced (i.e. a new file is created with the same name and size)?

Comment: That's exactly what I need. the `index.js` file makes named exports, and can be updated as new components / modules are created or deleted, so content is very important for the operation of the application. but index.js is dynamically generated so it will not be possible to fire new constructs.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with a watch option that will give you the behavior you are looking for out of the box. Perhaps someone else has some ideas. However if you are willing to share a little more information such as when your plug-in is triggered we may be able to approach this from another vector. Based on the little I have learned, it almost sounds like this would primarily be a problem at development time? In any case we may be able to solve this via timing and arrangement updates. Or perhaps leveraging your index file as a link to your generated files and excluding those.

Comment: I updated my question for better understanding my problem, if you can read it, be happy

Comment: Thanks for the updates Yung, this should be very helpful. I have to go meet my girlfriends family for dinner so won't be able to review until later, but another option I plan to look at is to see if we can intercept the WebPack hooks "completed" event to see if we could manually trigger an "everything is good" status thus circumventing the build during that polling cycle. I have a couple other thoughts too, but will need to review further once I get back and can give your updated question a closer look. P.S. I up voted the question in hopes more people will see it and have a chance to respond.

Comment: thank you very much for your attention, I'm very happy, I'll be waiting anxiously, I've been trying to solve this problem for days.

Comment: Try this in your watchOptions and let us know:                               
  "watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 3500
  }"                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                         
I'm not 100% sure this will suppress the issue for us due to the beforeCompile hook, but figured it's worth a shot since this will likely be the quickest work around by a fair margin.

Comment: the loop continues, only now with a delay

Comment: Interesting, what is the watch polling in the webpack.conf for project currently set for? Basically what we want to do is have the webpack watch polling detect the changes, then execute your plug-in before compilation (regenerate the index) and ideally have the aggregate timeout wait long enough to incorporate those changes into the pending build. Probably need some tweaking at minimum none the less or perhaps look at other pre compile intercept events. Trick might be we need to wait long enough for both your plugin to execute then the system I/O create and unlock the file in time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196119/discussion-between-ihazcode-and-yung-silva).